# match callback_context.triggered_id syntax error when deploying on Render.com

Tags: python, callback, render, plotly-dash

I have build a simple web app using dash & python and I want to deploy it on render.com.
My app builds and works correctly, when operating in local environment, but when I tried to deploy it I received the following error:

```
Jan 21 11:17:35 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/app.py", line 38
Jan 21 11:17:35 PM      match callback_context.triggered_id:
Jan 21 11:17:35 PM                           ^
Jan 21 11:17:35 PM  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

One of my callbacks has inputs from 2 buttons, so to distinguish that I am using `callback_context.triggered_id` method which seems to be a problem for render.

My requirements.txt file consists the following:

```
dash==2.6.2
pandas
gunicorn
```

and I think this may be a problem, that something related to `callback_context.triggered_id` should be included there as well, however I was unable to find what because apparently those methods are available in dash library from version 2.4.

I will greatly appreciate any support on this matter.

I tried looking for answers in the internet and in dash documentation but couldn't find anything that could help me.
I also tried `pip freeze > requirements_temp.txt` to find out what other dependencies are installed that I could use, but I was unable to track the one I'm looking for.

Comment: This feature requires Python 3.10 or later. Ensure that the right version runs the code.

Comment: that is a very good comment. I totally forgot that match/case statement has been available since the lates python release. Thanks!